# Ansible: how to use vars file with same key names

Tags: ansible

Could you please help to suggest whats the best approach to use a `vars_file` which will have keys with same.

`sample ansible playbook, where vars have used in dict format under loop.`

```
- name: Create real users
  user: name="{{item.user_name}}" shell="/bin/bash" uid="{{item.user_id}}"
  loop:
    - { user_name: "user1", user_id: "2000" }
    - { user_name: "user2", user_id: "2001" }
```

How to write the same ansible playbook with vars file having the same keys. I am not sure how to put these variables in YAML format.

please suggest. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply save the variables as a list of dicts in yaml.

```
vars:
  list_of_dicts:
    - user_name: "user1"
      user_id: "2000"
    - user_name: "user2"
      user_id: "2001"
```

and use your list of dicts like this:

```
- name: Create real users
  user: name="{{item.user_name}}" shell="/bin/bash" uid="{{item.user_id}}"
  loop:
    "{{ list_of_dicts }}"
```

Comment: Hi,, thanks for your response.. i have been looking for way to use loop for variables defined in file.

Comment: i have defined list_of_dicts:.....etc contents into a YAML file and used it under loop, but it doesnt work

Comment: Well then show what and how you have tried and what error message you get.